# Getting error while encrypting the password using salt in Python

Tags: python, hashlib

I am getting error while encrypting the password using Python. I am explaining the error below.

> Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "password.py", line 60, in <module>
    hashed_password = hashlib.sha512(sword + salt).hexdigest()
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

My code is given below.

```
import hashlib
value = "2Y7xk5vrs5DeCcSdinRVKQ=="
salt = value.split()
sword = "subhra1234"
hashed_password = hashlib.sha512(sword + salt).hexdigest()
print(hashed_password)
```

Here I need to use own salt value and trying to encrypting the password. Please help to resolve this error.

Comment: Why are you splitting `salt`? Do you know what `str.split` does? It produces a list...

Comment: otherwise its throwing the same error like `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list'`. Can you share solution or this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @MosesKoledoye said, you don't need to call split on the salt:

```
import hashlib
salt = "2Y7xk5vrs5DeCcSdinRVKQ=="
sword = "subhra1234"
hashed_password = hashlib.sha512(sword + salt).hexdigest()
print(hashed_password)
```